# Asp.net adding Values to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Im new to asp.net and i started with basic crud operations.

I made the css class with db name values (code,name,price,currency) and DBcontext  for this, when i made the controller it doesnt not add the values to the database but it's stored in somewhere.

[image]

When i use as a normal query from c# code, it's stored into the database.

My question is why does the CRUD operations from the (csfile and context) are not in the database?

--cs class--

```
public class Productos
{
    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public decimal Precio { get; set; }
    public string Moneda { get; set; }
}
```

-product context

```
public class ProductoContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductoContext() : base("database name")
    {
    }

     public DbSet<Productos> Producto { get; set; }

}
```

---this is the code to create---

```
    // GET: Productos/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Productos/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Codigo,Nombre,Precio,Moneda")] Productos productos)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Producto.Add(productos);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(productos);
    }
```

---- connection string------

Comment: **SHOW US** the code! How are you trying to insert new data into the database using the `Producto` class and the EF `DbContext` ??

Comment: can you show how are you performing those crud operations?

Comment: I made the controller with (cs class and dbcontext) which is generated  with the mvc controller with EF (i dont know if it works since i was doing a tutorial)

Comment: We need to see the code, how are you creating the Producto, how are you adding/removing etc. If not we cant tell you what you are doing wrong. Can you share it?

Comment: done,i dont know if that code works to insert values into the db

Comment: Is any error returned? What is your connection string?

Comment: there are no error returned,i will add connection string .

Comment: You shouldnt be posting an object that comes from the Client directly to the server, but at first glance It seems fine. Did you debug there to see "productos" has the data you expect"? Also is that the whole DbContext? Are you modifying how Producto gets mapped anywhere? Is the Id autogenerated?

Comment: The id is autogenerated,this is the conn string (cant add this on the main topic) :<add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelProductos.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelProductos.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelProductos.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source="server name";initial catalog="dbname" ;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> </connectionStrings>

Comment: Alex you can tag someone you are talking to here using "@name" because unless @Alejandro is following your question he won't know you answered his comment.

Comment: did you see that the model state is valid, i.e. it actually steps into the section of the code? if so, what is the sql generated?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro model was not valid, so it wasnt saving changes into db.